# Video frame with screenshot comparison

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I have a video processing app which uses **AVFoundation.h** header file in which the screenshots of the video are saved. Once the screenshots are uploaded using **UIImagepicker**, I want to play the video from that specific frame. For that i believe I should compare each frame of the video with the screenshot of the video taken.

1. How to compare two images (not just equality, If the images are almost alike it should be detected).
2. How to play a video from a particular frame.
3. Please go through the code and suggest me modifications to be done to compare frames of the video and screenshots. I have successfully  extracted the frames of the video into a tableview. But can't compare the images with the screenshots.

I went through most of the methods available in internet but couldn't find anything that matches my need. Thanks in advance. Happy Coding.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _framesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/****Image path***/Desktop/ImageExtract/ImageExtract/The          Avengers-Iron-man Vs Nuke scene.mp4"];

     NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @YES };

     AVAsset *myAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:options];

     self.imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:myAsset];

     Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([myAsset duration]);

    _times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (Float64 i = 0; i < durationSeconds; i++) // For 25 fps in 15 sec of Video
    {
    [_times addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(i, 60)]];
    }

    [_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:_times
                                     completionHandler:^(CMTime          requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                                  AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {

                                         NSString requestedTimeString = (NSString )
                                         CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, requestedTime));
                                         NSString actualTimeString = (NSString )
                                         CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, actualTime));
                                         NSLog(@"Requested: %@; actual %@", requestedTimeString, actualTimeString);


                                         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {

                                             NSLog(@"image generated");

                                             UIImage *generatedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
                                             [_imageArray addObject:generatedImage];
                                             NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/frame_%d.png", frameCount];
                                             NSString* pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

                                             [_framesArray addObject:filename];

                                             [UIImagePNGRepresentation(generatedImage) writeToFile: pngPath atomically: YES];

                                             NSLog(@"Frame name %@",filename);
                                             NSLog(@"Time of Frame %f",CMTimeGetSeconds(requestedTime));
                                             NSLog(@"Frames Array %@",_framesArray);

                                             frameCount++;

                                             }





                                         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed) {
                                             NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                             NSLog(@"image Array %@",_imageArray);

                                             NSLog(@"Count %d",_imageArray.count);



                                            _imageTable=[[UITableView alloc]init];
                                            _imageTable.frame=CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 400);
                                           _imageTable.dataSource=self;
                                          _imageTable.delegate=self;
                                            [self.view addSubview:_imageTable];

                                         }
                                         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled) {
                                             NSLog(@"Canceled");
                                         }


                                     }];



    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
     return _imageArray.count;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {

     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
     UIImageView *uuimage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
     uuimage.image=[_imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:uuimage];

     return cell;

     }
```

Comment: Computer vision is notoriously hard, and comparing frames is not the best way to do this--what if you have a frame that could match any number of timestamps within the source video? Better to store the screenshot and source timestamp together, and use that to resume playback.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I haven't thought that way. :) Will try and will surely let you know the results.

Comment: @palpatim : Thanks for the new idea you gave me. After so long time I finally got the frame-Image comparison.